# VB.net MySql is it possible to Alter Table Insert Data at the same time?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Is it possible to add new column and insert new data on that new column at the same time with one button?

Scenario was, I have one table, with one existing column say column1, inserting data from a txtbox. then i want to add new column where a new data will be stored from another txtbox.

i made a fixed string column name coid with an incrementing number each time a new column is added.

Here's my code inside a button click event but wasn't working.

```
coid = "coid" & num
Try
        Connection.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "insert into database.coidset (CourseID) values ('" & CourseIDTxtbox.Text & "')"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, Connection)
        DataReader = Command.ExecuteReader

        Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        Connection.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "alter table database.coidset add " & coid.ToString & " varchar(45) "
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, Connection)
        DataReader = Command.ExecuteReader
        Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try


    Try
        Connection.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "insert into database.coidset (" & coid.ToString & ") values ('" & COcombobox.Text & "')"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, Connection)
        DataReader = Command.ExecuteReader
        COListBox.Items.Add(COcombobox.Text)
        COListBox.SelectedIndex = -1
        COcombobox.ResetText()
        num = num + 1
        Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Output was, a data is stored in my CourseID and new columns are created each time i clicked the button but it does not store the new data on those new columns. ANy idea? thanks

Comment: was this a button you want to hit a few times? Is it possible, sure.

Comment: dynamically altering your table like this is a sign of incredibly bad table design... And you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) to boot.

Comment: why you use executereader instead of executenonquery when you execute inserts and ddl sentences??.

Comment: it is hard to take this question seriously. I am sure it appears serious to the op though.

Comment: This code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: thanks for the ideas guys. im very sorry my code is terrible. im still at learning stage and i really appreciated your concerns. thank you i was now able to solve the code though relatively easy.